# Issue with Segue / Parse Login coming back as nil?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm utilizing the RevealController Menu which slides out like Facebook. The issue I'm having is that when users login and click on the Profile Tab from the Menu it presents them with the Login View, rather then profile view.

My viewDidLoad on my ProfileView is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Checking if user is logged in, if not show Login View Controller.
    if (self.currentUser != nil)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
    }

    // SETTING THE BACKGROUND IMAGE OF THE VIEW
    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];

    [self.revealButtonItem setTarget: self.revealViewController];
    [self.revealButtonItem setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer: self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

}
```

This doesn't make sense to me considering the fact that once the apps launched viewDidLoad on the Profile, view is called because it's the main view. Once the user is logged in they have the options from the menu, but once the Profile one is clicked, it simply presents the Login screen again rather then Profile. So I'm assuming it's somehow reading currentUser is nil at that point. Any ideas?

Comment: This block of code you posted isn't really giving much insight into the issue.  Is self.currentUser definitely equal to [PFUser currentUser]?  Try replacing self.currentUser with [PFUser currentUser] to make sure.  If it is in fact the current user and the PFUser currentUser is nil, there's probably an issue in either your app delegate or login view.

Comment: Odd I changed it to make sure, and it worked now. I don't see how self.currentUser didn't work though when I had this defined in the header "@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *currentUser;" I suppose it doesn't work like that even though no errors were given. Simply kept the property and called "self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

Comment: No, you have to instantiate the variable…can't just define it with a header.  Glad it worked. :)